# Why it is okay to omit "the" in some cases only?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

I am wondering why saying: *Learn physics with Mr. Brown* sounds okay but if Mr. Brown teaches vegetable names, for example, it sounds awkward to say: *Learn vegetables with Mr. Brown*

Or *Learn vegetables with Mr. Brown* is fine and it's just me finding it sounding awkward?

Comment: The direct objects usually considered acceptable with 'learn' are restricted. Subject areas are usually fine (maths / English / botany / ancient history ...); '[the] names of ...' is often fine – but learn _about_ vegetables / plants / animals ....

Comment: If *vegetables* is metaphorical or metonymic, e.g. what you call that unit of your horticulture course, I would find *Learn vegetables with Mr. Brown* unexceptional. We had many undergraduate courses reduced to a single word: *[wines](https://www.hotelschool.cornell.edu/academics/courses/course.html?id=HADM4300)*, famously, but it was more fun to say casually *I'm taking [mushrooms](http://courses.cornell.edu/preview_course_nopop.php?catoid=12&coid=95576) with Prof. Hudler*.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with omitting _the_. You wouldn't say _learn the vegetables_, either. With or without _the_, vegetables isn't something you learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use *the* when you're referring to a specific topic, but it tends to be omitted when referring to a general area of study or a process.

So you use *the* in cases like:

> learn the alphabet
>   learn the multiplication table
>   learn the countries in Europe

but you omit it in:

> learn spelling
>   learn long division
>   learn geography

In the case of processes, you could consider this an abbreviation of a *how to* phrase, e.g.

> learn how to spell correctly
>   learn how to do long division